# Is the Dark Light ritual an invisibility cloak?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

> You create a source of dim light that allows you and those around you
>   to see without your being seen because of your light source.

Does the "without your being seen" part mean that the players are effectively invisible, or does it simply mean that they can't necessarily be spotted? I'm confused because dim light isn't very dark and usually only provide partial concealment, but the text makes it sound like the dim light grants them total concealment or full-on invisibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'because of your light source' is the important bit - the light is not visible to anyone else, but if there is another ambient light source, you can be seen.

To simplify - the spell is a light source that is not bright and shiny. It does not make anything invisible, but it will not ruin any stealth attempts in darkened conditions. It will not alert others of the presence of the light outside the area of the ritual.

Comment: I must admit, your answer didn't really help my confusion at all. Is your point that they are completely invisible only when they're already in darkness? And if so, what good is the ritual?

Comment: @Ravn Imagine your party is sneaking up to a town under cover of darkness.  You need a light source to see with, but a typical light source will give away your position.  This ritual is the solution.

Comment: The ritual does not really interact with invisibility or grant invisibility.  It grants light, but a special kind of light that will not by itself destroy your stealth.  If the creature could have seen you anyways, the ritual will not make it harder for them to see you.  but if the creature could not have seen you, the ritual will not make it easier for them to see you.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple terms: the character using the ritual is not subject to low-light or darkness penalties, but any observers (read: enemies) still are.

Comment: You should probably add 'in the area of the ritual' after 'penalties', and 'outside the area' after 'still are'. Then I'll upvote.